# Magento 2 : Get Items Ordered in Email Template

Tags: magento2, email-templates, items, order-items

I'm looking to achieve a product grid of items ordered in an email template upon successful product. This is what I'm trying to achieve, in this exact order for each product.

[image]

Is this doable? I can't seem to find variables to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to custom layout for order item like screen-sort in email?

Comment: Question is not clear. Please clarify what you want to achieve .